# I want to Delete document by logstash,but it throws a exception

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Now,I meet a question. My logstash configuration file as follows:

```
input {

    redis {
        host => "127.0.0.1"
        port => 6379
        db => 10
        data_type => "list"
        key => "local_tag_del"
    }

}

filter {
}

output {

    elasticsearch {
        action => "delete"
        hosts => ["127.0.0.1:9200"]
        codec => "json"
        index => "mbd-data"
        document_type => "localtag"
        document_id => "%{album_id}"
    }
    file {
            path => "/data/elasticsearch/result.json"
    }   
    stdout {}
}
```

I want to read id from redis, by logstash, notify es to delete document.

[image: exception picture]

Excuse me,My English is poor,I hope that someone will help me .
Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you particularly, because your problem is spelled out in your error message - logstash couldn't connect to your elasticsearch instance.

That usually means one of:

- elasticsearch isn't running
- elasticsearch isn't bound to localhost

That's nothing to do with your logstash config. Using logstash to delete documents is a bit unusual though, so I'm not entirely sure this isn't an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)